# accessing PostgreSQL running on docker from same physical machine

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am new to docker, Below is my Dockerfile section that starts postgreSQL:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

USER postgres

RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER postgres1 WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';" &&\
    createdb -O postgres1 password

RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

EXPOSE 5432

VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

i run the docker with command

```
docker run -p 5432:4006 c00d99a4b93e
```

Log after starting the Docker:

```
$ docker run -p 8080:4005 -p 5432:4006 c00d99a4b93e
2017-10-09 06:36:03.547 UTC [5] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-10-09 06:24:12 UTC
2017-10-09 06:36:03.586 UTC [5] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2017-10-09 06:36:03.587 UTC [5] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1784DA8
2017-10-09 06:36:03.587 UTC [5] LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1784DE8
2017-10-09 06:36:03.587 UTC [5] LOG:  redo done at 0/1784DA8
2017-10-09 06:36:03.587 UTC [5] LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2017-10-09 06:24:12.415859+00
2017-10-09 06:36:03.592 UTC [5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-10-09 06:36:03.596 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-10-09 06:36:03.602 UTC [9] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I am trying to commect to this database from my local machine using pgAdmin.

I have tried to connect to:
0.0.0.0:4006
127.0.0.1:4006

but I am getting Connection Refused exception.

here is the Docker ps output

```
$  docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                          NAMES
72191e69bf5a        c00d99a4b93e        "/usr/lib/postgresql/"   39 seconds ago      Up 37 seconds       5432/tcp, 8009/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->4005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->4006/tcp   modest_lalande
```

Could you help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this on windows or linux ?

Comment: on windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should be inverted:

```
-p 8080:4005 -p 5432:4006
```

To this:

```
 -p 4005:8080 -p 4006:5432
```

Also if you are using docker on windows with the docker toolbox the ip of the machine will be different(192.168.99.100 by default not localhost)